# A free group construction with real (not integral) exponents?

Tags: group-theory

The construction of free groups, on considers "reduced" formal products of letters/symbols with integer exponents.  One example of an element in the free group over the letters $\{a, b, c\}$ might be $a^2b^{-1}a^4c^{-3}$.  Notice again that the exponents are integers.

What results if you take this construction, but allow real exponents so that elements such as $a^{1.5}b^{-3.1}c^{4.5}$ may be considered?  One could imagine elements in this group as follows:  think of the letters/symbols as colors and a group element as a concatenation of directed line segments of various colors with the obvious group operations.

I figure there is a name for this.  Is this construction useful and/or widespread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be described as the [free product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product) of copies of the reals, i.e., with three generators, we have $\mathbb R*\mathbb R*\mathbb R$.

Comment: Actually this is the free product.

Comment: @LeeMosher Rigth, there's nothing being amalgamated